# D3.js - Add circles/oval shapes around Cluster in a scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a very simple scatterplot:

```
 var data = [
  [10, 20], [20, 100], [200, 50],
  [25, 80], [10, 200], [150, 75],
  [10, 70], [30, 150], [100, 15]
]

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 250)
            .attr("height", 250)

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data).enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {return d[0]})
   .attr("cy", function(d) {return d[1]})
   .attr("r", 7)
   .attr("fill", function(d){
      if(d[0] > 50) {
         return "red"
      } else {
         return "green"
      }
   })
```

This is the current result

[image]

However I have to connect the diffferent colors and draw a non-rectangle shape around each "cluster". The desired result would look like this:

[image]

I am not very familiar with D3.js and was not able to create an oval-shaped SVG. Does anyone have a solution or at least a hint how I can tackle this problem?

Comment: Check out `ellipse` in svg

Comment: This example might interest you: https://bl.ocks.org/XavierGimenez/a8e8c5e9aed71ba96bd52332682c0399

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is the following:

1. Separate the green and the red samples
2. Get the mean X and Y coordinates
3. Get the min/max X and Y for both groups
4. Use the mean and min/max X,Y for each group to draw an ellipse

```js
var data = [
  [10, 20], [20, 100], [200, 50],
  [25, 80], [10, 200], [150, 75],
  [10, 70], [30, 150], [100, 15]
]

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 450)
            .attr("height", 650)

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data).enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {return d[0]})
   .attr("cy", function(d) {return d[1]})
   .attr("r", 7)
   .attr("fill", function(d){
      if(d[0] > 50) {
         return "red"
      } else {
         return "green"
      }
   })

// Clustering code starts here:

// Separate into 2 clusters: red and green (>50)
const clusters = data
.reduce((acc,value)=>{
  if ( value[0] > 50 ){
    acc.red.push(value);
  } else {
    acc.green.push(value);
  }
  return acc;

},{red:[],green:[]});

// Get the average X and Y from all green samples to determine the center of the ellipse:
const greenX = d3.mean(clusters.green, d => d[0]);
const greenY = d3.mean(clusters.green, d => d[1]);
const [ greenXMin, greenXMax ] = d3.extent(clusters.green, d => d[0]);
const [ greenYMin, greenYMax ] = d3.extent(clusters.green, d => d[1]);

// Do the same for the red samples:
const redX = d3.mean(clusters.red, d => d[0]);
const redY = d3.mean(clusters.red, d => d[1]);
const [ redXMin, redXMax ] = d3.extent(clusters.red, d => d[0]);
const [ redYMin, redYMax ] = d3.extent(clusters.red, d => d[1]);

// Draw the ellipses. First green, then red:
svg.append('ellipse')
    .attr('cx', greenX)
    .attr('cy', greenY)
    .attr("rx", greenXMax - greenXMin + 20)
    .attr("ry", greenYMax - greenYMin + 5)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', '#00ff0055');

svg.append('ellipse')
    .attr('cx', redX)
    .attr('cy', redY)
    .attr("rx", redXMax - redXMin + 20)
    .attr("ry", redYMax - redYMin + 5)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', '#ff000055');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```